# FileNotFoundError while opening file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've searched and cannot find how to fix this. I am watching a tutorial and I created a file called "testfile" in notepad. It's a .txt file. When I type

```
file1 = open("testfile.txt", "r")
```

in to python I get this error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'testfile.txt'
```

What can I do to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: the file exists?

Comment: Have you started your python interpreter in the same directory?

Comment: give the full path

Comment: `import os; os.getcwd()` shows the current folder. `os.listdir('.')` shows its content.

Answer (score 0):

Are they in the same directory? The `testfile.py` and your python code need to be in the same directory to be able to find the file. Otherwise, testfile needs to have its path specified.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with the path. I assume your file `testfile.txt` is located in the same directory where you run your script, called the *working directory*. Please, try `./testfile.txt`. This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving out the entire location of the file like on desktop or the C drive wherever that is, E.g.: `c:\users\desktop\testfile`

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that the file "testfile.txt" is in the same folder as your running code.
Then code like this will work:

```
with open("testfile.txt","r") as fileTest:
    rawLines = fileTest.readlines()
```

Oh, and by the way, nice username.

Comment: It needs to be not the same folder *as the running code*, but the same folder *that is the current working directory of the user who's running the code*. If I'm in the directory `/foo` and run `python /bar/some.py`, and that script tries to open `hello.txt`, it'll be looking for `/foo/hello.txt`, not `/bar/hello.txt`.