# FileNotFoundError in opening txt file with python

Tags: python, file, error-handling

I am trying to open a txt file for reading with this code:-

```
type_comments = [] #Declare an empty list
with open ('society6comments.txt', 'rt') as in_file:  #Open file for reading of text data.
 for line in in_file: #For each line of text store in a string variable named "line", and
   type_comments.append(line.rstrip('\n'))  #add that line to our list of lines.
```

Error:-

```
Error  - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/sultan/python/society6/society6_promotion.py", line 6, in <module>
    with open ('society6comments.txt', 'rt') as in_file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'society6comments.txt'
```

I already have a file name with 'society6comments.txt' in the same directory has my script so why is it showing error?

[image]

Comment: Give it the full path, just to see what happens

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FileNotFoundError: \[Errno 2\] No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22282760/filenotfounderror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: Another similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48200441/filenotfounderror-while-opening-file-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `os.path.dirname(__file__)` to obtain the directory name of the script, and then join the file name you want:

```
import os
with open (os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'society6comments.txt'), 'rt') as in_file:
```

Comment: you want `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), "yourfile.ext")`

Comment: Only if the OP does a `chdir` yes; otherwise `dirname` would always be valid from the current working directory. I've updated my answer just in case though. Thanks.

Comment: I once had some fun debugging a similar problem, and it happened that some very poorly written module I was importing DID a chdir.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that the text file is in the same directory as your program does not make that directory the current working directory. Put the full path to the file in your `open()` call.

Comment: When is the directory your py file is in not the working dir?

Comment: @SuperStew whenever you run the script from another place, whenever anything in the chain (for example a badly written module you import in your script) changes the working dir, and I'm not even talking about what can happen when your "py file" is used as a module instead of a script.

Comment: Interesting. Somehow I haven't run into that issue yet. good to know though